# How to implement a function with a sum inside in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to define a function with a for loop and inside a conditional in R studio. Yesterday I was able with the help of another thread to devise this piece of code. The problem is that I want to sum the vector elements ma for any possible x, so that is inside the function l. This is a simpler case which I am trying to solve to adapt the original model. However, I do not know how to proceed.

```
ma<-rep(0,20)
l <- function(x, ma) {
             for(i in seq_along(ma)) {
                 if(i %% 2 == 1) {
                     ma[i] <- i + x
                  } else {
                     ma[i] <- 0
            }
            }
        return(ma)
       }
```

My problem is that I would like to have the sum of i+x+0+i+x... for any possible x. I mean a function of the kind [image: $$\sum_{i=1}^k i \mathbb{1}_{i mod 2=1 }+x$$] for any possible x.

**Question:**

Can someone explain to me how to implement such a function in R?

Thanks in advance!

I am going to update the original function:

```
Theta_alpha_s<-function(s,alpha,t,Basis){

for (i in seq_along(Basis)){
  if(i%% 2==1) {Basis[i]=s*i^{-alpha-0.5}*sqrt(2)*cos(2*pi*i*t)}
  
  else{Basis[i]=s*i^{-alpha-0.5}*sqrt(2)*sin(2*pi*i*t)}
  
  
}
return(Basis)
}
```

Comment: So in your example, you're looking for (1 + 0) + 0 + (3 + 2) + 0 + (5 + 4) + ...?

Comment: @Benjamin          For every possible x, not for a pre-defined x. I want to adapt the code for an optimization problem of let's say the variable, x after summation. But I cannot sum a function with a variable or variables. So I wanted to incorporate the sum inside the function.

Comment: @Benjamin Please see the update in my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to change the values in Basis, you can create a new vector in the function (here `result`) that you will return:

```
l = function(s,alpha,t,Basis){
  is.odd = which(Basis %% 2 == 1)
  not.odd = which(Basis %% 2 == 0)
  result = rep(NA, length(Basis))
  result[is.odd] = s*is.odd^{-alpha-0.5}*sqrt(2)*cos(2*pi*is.odd*t)
  result[not.odd] = s*not.odd^{-alpha-0.5}*sqrt(2)*sin(2*pi*not.odd*t)
  #return(result)
  return(c(sum(result[is.odd]), sum(result[not.odd])))
}
```

Comment: No, I want to define a function with a sum inside. The sum is part of the function since I cannot sum afterwards with a variable. Because I am looking forward to optimization of a function of the kind I wrote above in the picture.

Comment: I tried to update my post that the sum is made in a function. Not sure that's what you expect though.

Comment: Please see my update. I need to sum the two conditions of the "if "statement.

Comment: However I do not know how to do it while keeping the variables.

Comment: like it is now?

Comment: You do not have x as a variable on the summation.

Comment: x was a variable I defined for the simple case, to see how this works.

Comment: Is result the sum of all elements the odd with the even ones?

Comment: no, you have a vector that is the result of a different operation for odd and even indices. if you want to sum up all odd values: sum.odd.values = sum(result[is.odd]). Is it what you want?

Comment: The problem is that I cannot sum with variables like s,alpha. So how do I write the sum? The problem when I run the function with l(1,2,3,ma), it does not return any values.

Comment: I want the sum to be part of the function.

Comment: Thanks for the support but the function is not running.

Comment: Thanks again! To get what I wanted I modified your last line  into return(sum(c(sum(result[is.odd]), sum(result[not.odd])))) but it is not working.